# Understand "Merge two sorted linked lists" on hackerrank

Tags: linked-list

*(migrated from [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/252220))*

The question comes from the HackerRank problem [Merge two sorted linked lists](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/one-week-preparation-kit-merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=preparation-kits&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-week-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-week-day-five):

> ###### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 1
> 3
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```
>
> ###### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 1 2 3 3 4
> ```
>
> ###### Explanation
>
> The first linked list is: 1→3→7→Null
> The second linked list is: 3→4→Null
> Hence, the merged linked list is:  1→2→3→3→4→Null

I have two questions:

1. How does the sample input correspond to the explanation section? There is no "7".
2. In the explanation,
   "The first linked list is: 1->3->7->Null"
   but in the merged list there is no "7". Why does "7" disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mistake. The first linked list is: 1→2→3→Null

Answer (score 0):

A careful reading of the question/explanation reveals the answer.

The first value represents the number of test cases: (1). The second represents the number of elements in the first list: (3) {1,2,3}. The third represents the number of elements in the second list: (2) {3,4}. There is no value of 7 in either list.